# Match text after colon and before new line - Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a text in the following format:

```
Concept number 1: my content here1<br>
Concept number 2: my content here2<br>
Concept number 3: my content here3<br>
```

I want a regext to get the text after `Concept number 1:`. So I want to get the following: `my content here1`.

I was using `Concept number 1(.*?)<br>`, but I'm getting the whole string as a result instead of the text after the colon.

[Demo online](http://jsfiddle.net/zya58vn0/).

```
var text = $('.text').html();
var regex = new RegExp('Concept number 1:(.*?)<br>', "g");
var matches = text.match(regex);
//matches contains `Concept number 1: my content here1<br>`
```

Comment: So you are matching "Name and Surname:" although in the text to match it reads "Concept number *:" and you are wondering why it doesn't match?

Comment: @Connum that was a typo... obviously :)

Comment: "*I'm getting the whole string as a result*" No, you're not.

Comment: @melpomene am I not? Have you checked the ´matches` content? It's an array with 1 dimension containing `Concept number 1: my content here1<br>`

Comment: You need to use captured group #1 for your text.

Comment: @anubhava and thus my question. How do I do that?

Comment: @Alvaro That's not the whole string.

Comment: @melpomene clearly is not "the text after the colon" I want to get, call it whatever :)

Comment: Somewhat buried in the docs for [String.prototype.match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) it says "if you want to obtain capture groups and the global flag is set, you need to use RegExp.exec() instead."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `regex.exec()` instead of `.match()`. Then you can access the matching groups as an ordinary array:

```js
var text = $('.text').html();
var regex = new RegExp('Concept number 1:(.*?)<br>');
var matches = regex.exec(text);

console.log(matches[1]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text">
Concept number 1: my content here1<br>
Concept number 2: my content here2<br>
Concept number 3: my content here3<br>
</div>
```

Comment: Why use `g` at all?

Comment: Good catch, just copied that over from the question

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would work off the DOM and not the innerHTML

```js
var text = $('.text').contents()  //get all the textnodes and elements
             .filter( function (i, node) { //get just the text nodes
               return node.nodeType==3
             }).map( function (i, node) {  //get the text you are after
               var match = node.nodeValue.match(/:\s+(.*)/)
               return match ? match[1] : undefined
            }).get()  //turn jQuery object into array
console.log(text)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text">
Concept number 1: my content here1<br>
Concept number 2: my content here2<br>
Concept number 3: my content here3<br>
</div>
```

Comment: Why? Sounds more complicated

Comment: Because matching HTML with a regular expression is not the best thing in the world. The code above could skip the filter line and just do the match.